# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvc2k/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp]

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a Spring project. When I call the URL it is calling the controller and printing the result in console. But the requestmapping method prints the output but not displaying the view / jsp page.

Please find the below link for better understanding.

My Spring Project Structure:

[image: My Spring Project Structure]

the controller is called and printing 'IN' as output:

[image: the controller is called and printing 'IN' as output]

The controller i been using.

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String getRespnse(Model m) {
        System.out.println("IN");
        return "home";
    }

}
```

This the view resolver I'm using.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I cannot able view the jsp output in browser.Please suggest a way to handle.

Comment: Please post code of the controller from where you are returning the view name.

Comment: views folder should be outside the WEB-INF folder. Means it will be inside webapps directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you map your DispatcherServlet to url pattern /* in your web.xml it overrides all other url mappings specified. To handle JSPs web containers includes a mapping *.jsp to handle JSPs.

So you mapping overrides the container`s *.jsp servlet and requests for servlets are now going through your DispatcherServlet which doesnt know how to handle JSPs.

Change your url-pattern from /* to /

Comment: Thank you so much.it worked like a charm. can u explain more. how it worked.So i  could get a better understanding.

Comment: This is defined by Servlet url mapping rules. The following article has a detailed explanation http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/